# Example for intersection, multiplicity and tangents for projective plane curves

Tags: examples-counterexamples, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, projective-space

We recently got introduced to projective plane curves in our class, however we just defined it and never really talked about examples. And when I am trying to come up with a just any curve, calculating the multiplicity at a point is rather hard (in comparison to the affine case at least). So could someone give me a simple (but not completely trivial) example of $1$ or $2$ curves and calculate multiplicities, tangents and/or the intersection of them.
Thank you in advance!